# Win forms, panel

Tags: c#, winforms

В форме есть панель, как сделать так чтобы при полном открытии формы, панель тоже стала больше?

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь свойством `Dock` (это свойство можно также задать в дизайнере):

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    panel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}
```

Значение `DockStyle.Fill` позволяет "прикрепить" размер контрола к размеру родительского контрола.

Answer (score 0):

Если не хотите чтобы panel стала на все окно, а чтобы между краями форми бил промежуток, тогда используйте anchor

`panel1.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top);`